# How do I add Models to my backoffice from a settings file

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 
I'ld like to have a config file that says which models to display in my backoffice and which glyphicon to use for the display in the navigation bar.
I want some kind of config file to load that from and I'm looking for the best way to do that.

Comment: When you say "which models to display in my backoffice" you mean menu items?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you referring to Laravel Database Models?

Comment: yes I mean menu-items, so that that a record of that Model can be added to the database and the tables can be viewed and so on...

Comment: And yes I am referring to database models